# I am the light that shines in the dark

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

First go at writing a riddle, here goes:

> I am the light that shines in the dark
>   Sometimes I've a friend to whom you should hark
>
> There's no match for me,
>   I'm buzzing with energy
>
> If you see me, you might be too near
>   Perhaps your direction, you need to shear
>
> Don't get too salty, please don't pout
>   My head keeps twisting around and about

Might be fairly easy to ardent puzzlers, but hope you enjoy!

Comment: A distant cousin of mine keeps claiming to be the terror that flaps in the night.  Apparently this isn't about him though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Could you be

> A lighthouse

I am the light that shines in the dark
Sometimes I've a friend to whom you should hark

> A lighthouse provides light when it's dark or foggy, and the friend refers to a foghorn (who you should also heed)

There's no match for me,
I'm buzzing with energy

> Lighthouses take energy to light - may also be a play on words since it's not a fire (no match needed) but electrical light (buzzing energy)

If you see me, you might be too near
Perhaps your direction, you need to shear

> If you can see the lighthouse while on the water, you are much too close and need to change direction

Don't get too salty, please don't pout
My head keeps twisting around and about

> Salty refers to the salty sea air, and the head of the lighthouse indeed twists (the light spins round and round)

Comment: That was quick! Spot on though with all points! (I'll accept in 3 minutes haha)